# how to remove the value heading in pivot table in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

I want to create a pivot table and for that I have written the code below

```
pvt_df = df1.pivot_table(index=["Title"],values=['Rating'],columns=["Gender"], aggfunc='mean')
pvt_df.head()
```

I am getting the output as

[image]

but I want the desired output as

[image]

I just want to remove the "Rating" which is values heading.I tried few but couldn't get it.Can anyone please help me with this, It would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Somehow I could find my answer after looking into this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html.
If you have a value heading above all.You can get rid of it by using below
I just wrote this

```
pvt_df["Rating"].head()
```

After adding this I got my desired output